# Jquery data tables need to show only selected rows from an integer array of IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have a drop down with checkboxes in it. When I select multiple items, I have a method which gets those IDs in an integer array. In my data table one of the column, lets say 'User_ID:name' has those IDs. I want to loop through the data table and show only rows of selected IDs in the integer array. If array is empty, no rows should be visible.

I wrote a method, but it's only showing me only 1 row and it keeps overwriting that row when looping through.

```
var Gridupdate = function () {
    int[] checked = Checkbox.getCheckedIds(); /// integer array of selectedIDs from a checkbox
    if (dtable) {
        for (i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
            dtable.column("User_ID:name").search(checked[i].toString()).draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` in *"DataTables"* to achieve this. Add this to your *"DataTables' initialisation options"*.

```
"search": {
    "regex": true, // enables the table to be filtered using regular expresion
    "smart": false // disables the table's "smart search" ability. Ensures a more accurate search.
}
```

Example:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "search": {
        "regex": true,
        "smart": false
    }
});
```

And change your method to this

```
var Gridupdate = function () {
    var checked = Checkbox.getCheckedIds(); /// integer array of selectedIDs from a checkbox
    if (dtable) {
        dtable.column("User_ID:name").search(checked.join('|')).draw(); // eg .search(1|2|4)
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ruleboy21.  I wanted to display the  corresponding rows only the ones which are selected in checkbox. LIke I've a multi checkbox with IDs 1,2,3 &4. and corresponding rows in data table. On initial load, all the records in data table should be hidden. Then when I selected chkbox 1, corresponding data table row should be visible. Again when checking chkbox 2, that row should be visible too. So like how many chkbox selected, all those corresponding rows should be visible in datat table and unchecked chkbox value's corresponding rows should be hidden.

Comment: I think you should add your code to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so I can understand it better.